# EKS can only run 2 pod of Fargate concurrently

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-fargate

this is my situation: 
I follow this guide to build my cluster on EKS (with **fargate** profile): `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-console.html`. But when i installing my helm chart, only 2 pods can run properly, another ones got *pending* status with this message: *Your AWS account has reached the limit on the number of Fargate pods it can run concurrently*. 
Anyone could help my fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Can you check what the Fargate concurrent task quota is in your account? (search for `Service Quotas` in the console and then search for Fargate)

Comment: i have checked, its apply value is 100

Answer (score 1):

Your region has not yet been activated.  You have to launch an EC2 instance and terminate it to get past this error.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=292840

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution: provide `ec2FullAccess` for IAM user.

Comment: Mh... that is weird. I am not sure what that policy would do to Fargate.... mh...

Answer (score 0):

I have found that even though the `AWS Default Quota` for Fargate tasks is high, the `Applied Quota` for new accounts is `2`, which is stunningly low. I am in the same situation, and I have requested a quota increase.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. We had more than 20 tasks running, but suddenly new tasks have stopped. Upon checking Service quotas, the applied quota value was just 2. Did requesting a quota increase help?

Comment: Yes, it took a while but eventually I did get a higher quota